# Git branch -m and remote tracking branches

Tags: git

I have a branch I've already pushed to github using --set-upstream. I want to rename it now, and have that change reflected on github. Here's what I want to do

```
git branch -m oldbranch newbranch
git push origin :oldbranch
git push --set-upstream newbranch
```

Running 'branch -m' doesn't update my .git/config apart from changing the branch to 'newbranch'. branch.newbranch.merge is still 'refs/heads/oldbranch'. When I push if I issue the command

```
git push --set-upstream origin newbranch
```

is that going to properly update my .git/config? Any potential impact on other users? No one else is currently committing to the branch, and I don't think anyone's even checked it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should push `newbranch` to `origin` and update the upstream info. If you want to be really explicit, you can use `git push --set-upstream origin newbranch:newbranch`.

As for impacting other users, you're proposing to delete the original branch (`oldbranch`) and create a new branch (`newbranch`). They just happen to have the same names. However, other users won't "magically" get the branch name change. Anyone who's following your `oldbranch` will see the branch get deleted, and anyone who blindly pushes their copy of `oldbranch` may inadvertently re-create the branch on the server.

Answer (score 1):

While there probably are git plumbing command to rename the upstream and the local branches, I wouldn't really bother much about it.

A workflow that is simple is to create a new branch from the branch-you-want-renamed with the new-name-you-want, and then go about deleting the old branch and then you push the branch, it goes with your new-name

```
git checkout oldname
git branch newbranch
git branch -d oldname
git push newbranch
```

Because a branch is identified by it's name, old users who may be tracking this earlier branch will be affected and some may, if they have corresponding permissions, end up creating a branch with that name.